# Could this be the n + 1 problem?

Tags: hibernate, orm

In a program I have to maintain, there is one point where a single, simple query is executed.

The query looks like this:

```
<named-query name="retrievePolicySet">
    <query>from PSTRepresentationType p where p.realm=? AND p.policySetType.policySetId=?</query>
</named-query>
```

The type `PSTRepresentationType` has a many-to-one association, mapping many `PolicySetType`s to one `PSTRepresentationType`.

When the query gets executed, it not only creates one but 45 additional select statements!
Could this be a n + 1 problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. I believe for your case the left join fetch solution should work: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernate-query-101/.